# Why does Golang use string slice in url.Values, rather than single string?

Tags: go

In Golang, why url.Values uses string slice as value:

```
type Values map[string][]string
```

rather than single string:

```
type Values map[string]string
```

Isn't it simpler to use single string? Are there more considerations about this?

Comment: *"Isn't it simpler to use single string?"* -- No, it isn't. Both query parameters and form values, for which `url.Values` is primarily used, allow for multiple values per key. If `url.Values` was using a single string per key, then everyone who depends on `url.Values` would have to parse that single string themselves.

Comment: In addition to what @mkopriva said, `url.Values` has the method `Get()` which serves for exactly what you possibly had in mind: it sacrifices flexibility for simplicity of usage.

Comment: You are right, I neglected the multiple values situation.

Comment: This is about URL allows one query key can have many values, not about Golang.

Answer (score 1):

Type `url.Values` is meant to represent a *common syntax* used in the query. The problem with this convention is that it was never fully formalized as a specification.

“Uniform Resource Locators (URL)” RFC 1738 has no mention under “HTTP” subsection 3.3. “URI Generic Syntax” RFC 3986 states “… as query components are often used to carry identifying information in the form of "key=value" …” which hardly means anything. “HTTP/1.1” RFC 2616 and followup skip the subject entirely.

As a result, query parameters are used with multiple values or even no value at all, i.e, `?a&b=1&c=2&c=3` is tolerated by most.

Go's `Get gets the first value associated with the given key.` can result in tricky behaviour, in favour of more readable code. For security reasons and reliability I recommend to trigger an error case for multiple values. If one-liners are really what you need, then at least do `strings.Join(q[key], "")` on `url.Values` `q` to get some consistent results.